# Cannot stream large table to browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET webforms app on winhost.com with a supporting SQL Server Database. I can successfully download all the tables except for the largest one (193mb). I've searched and searched for what I am being blocked by without luck.

I tried maxing out the maxRequest and ContentLength in the web.config with no success. 
`<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="36000" />
<requestFiltering>
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
</requestFiltering>`

My streaming pseudocode is as follows:

```
Write the whole table to stringBuilder object
```

`Convert that to byte Array`

```
Stream to Browser

public void StreamFileToBrowser(string sFileName, byte[] fileBytes)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ClearHeaders();
        context.Response.ClearContent();
        context.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
        context.Response.ContentType = GetMimeTypeByFileName(sFileName);
        context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sFileName);
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);

        // use this instead of response.end to avoid thread aborted exception (known issue):
        // http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/EN-US
        context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your logs?  What happens on this request/

Comment: Try setting `Response.BufferOutput = false;`